# Getting Response too large exception when executing rest api POST using RestTemplate SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, java-resources, ellucian-banner

I am getting **Response too large** when executing exchange (type POST) method from Spring Boot restTemplate.
Below is the output

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Response too large","extensions":{"code":"413","responseSizeKb":1901.147,"responseSizeMaxKb":1000}}]}
```

I need to increase response size. Not sure how to do that.

Below are the code and httpHeaders

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, this.getHttpEntity(), String.class, new Object[0]);


headers.add(Authorization, TOKEN_TYPE_BEARER + authKey);
headers.add(CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.ALL));
headers.add("Connection", "keep-alive");
headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

I tried to increase content-length but no luck

```
headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, "179974");
```

Can anyone please help me to increase response size ?

Comment: Is this error raised by Spring RestTemplate itself, or is the error produced by the server you are trying to connect to?

Please add the complete exception.

Comment: HI @larsgrefer Thanks for checking. Below is the output from resttemplate.exchange method.<200,{"errors":[{"message":"Response too large","extensions":{"code":"413","responseSizeKb":1901.147,"responseSizeMaxKb":1000}}]},[Date:"Mon, 14 Aug 2023 22:22:08 GMT", Content-Type:"application/json; charset=utf-8", Content-Length:"124", Connection:"keep-alive", server:"awselb/2.0", x-media-type:"application/vnd.hedtech.integration.v1.0.0+json", vary:"origin", access-control-expose-headers:"x-max-page-size,x-media-type,x-total-count,x-content-restricted,hedtech-ethos-integration-application-id,

Comment: looks like the server you are trying to connect has this "responseSizeMaxKb" settings. try adding more filters to reduce response data or increase value for "responseSizeMaxKb".

Comment: Thanks all for your reply. Yes after further analysis, it is found that server is restricting the response size . we added more filter to resolve the issue.